# How to use col-sm inline?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two blocks using Bootstap 3:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">A</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">B</div>
</div>
```

When I am in mobile mode, block are placed under each other.

How to place them inline until there is free space?

Comment: you need `col-xs-*` for mobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI in bootstrap 3 we got four major breakpoints as below:

**lg:** Large devices Desktops (≥1200px)

**md:** Medium devices Desktops (≥992px)

**sm:** Small devices Tablets (≥768px)

**xs:** Extra small devices Phones (<768px)

Each of them got **12 columns** with even size and **15px** gutter from left and right.

For more information, you can checkout bootstrap grid system documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid).

To create a responsive 2 column row in all major breakpoints, since `col-xs-*` using `max-width` media query and all other use `min-width`, all you have to do is to create two columns with `col-xs-6` and `col-sm-6` and wrap them into a `row` just like below:

```css
div.row>div {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 bg-info">A</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 bg-success">B</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**NOTE:** I just add `container-fluid`, `padding: 20px;` and background colors for better illustration.